# How do I change the units shown on the x-axis labels on a Matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to make it so the ticks on the x-axis for revenue show the value as a factor of a million rather than as a factor of a hundred million as they are now. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. My code and the resulting bar chart is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.display import display
from pandas import Series

%matplotlib inline


# Define Figure Size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,25))

# Get the average vote_average for each genre
average_revenue = df2.groupby('release_year')['revenue_adj'].mean()

# Find positions of y ticks
y_pos = np.arange(len(df2['release_year'].unique()))
# Set up Bar Chart
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(sorted(df2['release_year'].unique()))
ax.set_xlabel('Revenue in Millions', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Release Year', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Revenue by Release Year', fontsize=20)

# Set Size of X and Y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=14)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=14)

# Put Values next to Each Bar
for i, v in enumerate(average_revenue):
    a = v/1000000
    ax.text(v, i, ('$' + str(round(a,2)) + 'M'), color='blue')
    
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom

# Draw Bar Chart
ax.barh(y_pos, average_revenue, align='center', color='green', ecolor='black')
```

[image: Python Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the data is shown in ones, not millions or hundreds of millions. Notice the `1e8` on the right of the plot. You can plot the value in millions by dividing the input by a million:

```
ax.barh(y_pos, average_revenue * 1e-6, ...)
```

Alternatively, you can adjust the [formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) on the x-axis if you prefer not to alter the data. For example, you could use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) like this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x * 1e-6:0.1f}'))
```